# Spinner and Button cannot go to another view

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent

I need to put spinner into list view, example if i choose spinner "GARMENT 1" when i click button go to another view

```
tombol = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_submit);
    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    tombol.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (spinner.equals("GARMENT 1")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, gm1.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            if (spinner.equals("GARMENT 2")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, gm2.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to get the selected items from the spinner like below. after then you can compare that selected item with "GARMENT 1", "GARMENT 2", etc...

```
    String selectedItem = "";
String[] item = getResources().getStringArray(R.array. area_gm);
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,   android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, item);
spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); // The drop down view
spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
            selectedItem = item[position]; // here item is your list
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
            // your code here
        }
    
    });


tombol.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (selectedItem.equals("GARMENT 1")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, gm1.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            if (selectedItem.equals("GARMENT 2")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, gm2.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
```

Comment: <string-array name="area_gm">
        <item>PILIH AREA AUDIT</item>
        <item>GARMENT 1</item>
        <item>GARMENT 2</item>
        <item>GARMENT 3</item>
        <item>GARMENT 4</item>
        <item>CUTTING</item>
        <item>SERI WORKSHOP</item>
        <item>SERI WAREHOUSE</item>
        <item>LINE 12</item>
    </string-array>

Comment: @AyuAsriLestari : is that fixed.?

Comment: its fixed, but i want go to another view when i click button 'tombol' if i already choose the spinner. ex, i choose spinner "GM 1" then i click button. so, i will go to intent GM 1

Comment: @AyuAsriLestari You can use the argument `position` of `onItemSelected()` method in `switch-case statement`. More-ever have a look on this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/19915000/9129342